# Rolling back to old application in IBM WebSphere?

Tags: deployment, websphere, rollback

now we are going to deploy a new version from our applications, to avoid any risk we planed to design a roll back plan , so please anyone have an idea about how we can roll back the old version from application on IBM WebSphere application server , please i need it ASAP .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't yet deployed the new version, you can export a copy of the existing application as an EAR file through the WAS console (which you can then use as a backup to deploy if there are problems with the new version). In WAS 6.1, the process looks like this:

Applications > Enterprise Applications > Select the relevant application > Export.

Comment: This is correct. There is no internal way to roll-back. You'll have to reinstall an older version, and this is the way to obtain that older version if you no longer have it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Anthony Grist and dbreaux, there is no rollback facility.

You can do this though.

1. Shut down the current server
2. Create another server with the same port(s) (if you don't wnat to change anything)  as the current server
3. Install the new copy/versions of your application to the new server.

Test things out.

If things fail, shut down your new server. Turn on your current server and you are good to go. The same approach can be used for both clustered as well as non-clustered environments.

HTH